# Voxel remesh in 2.9 has random broken ‘pores’ (pics), is there a fix?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I’ve searched on this topic and haven’t seen it addressed anywhere. I've also posted to blender devtalk on this but haven't heard from anyone yet.
When I voxel remesh a somewhat complex shape, I always get several (sometimes a lot) random weird holes (I’m calling them pores) in the result. I don’t think they are ‘poles’ because they occur even with pole correction on.

Below are a couple pictures of before remeshing and after, also showing a larger pore ‘blowout’.
I really need the voxel remesher (it is critical to my workflow) but I can’t fix this problem. I’ve tried everything from subdividing or decimating the original mesh and smoothing, relaxing, etc. with no luck. The ‘pores’ just move to different locations. If I increase the voxel density the pores just get smaller and often (but not always) different locations.

I’m really hoping somebody can help with this because I’m at a ***dead stop*** in my project until I can fix this.
Anybody else have this problem? Is it a known problem that I’ve missed in my searches?
Thanks any help is super-appreciated.

Original triangular (fully manifold, no intersections) mesh and description of ‘pores’ and ‘blowouts’:
[image]